# Pythonic way to do conditionally assign variables

Tags: python

Any suggestions on how to do that in Python?

```
if x():
  a = 20
  b = 10
else:
  a = 10
  b = 20
```

I can swap them as below, but it's not as clear (nor very pythonic IMO)

```
a = 10
b = 20
if x():
  [a, b] = [b, a]
```

Comment: or I could do [a,b]=[20,10] ... [a,b]=[10,20]. Not sure it's much better

Comment: As a side note: You don't need (and probably don't want) the square brackets there. You can swap tuples as easily as lists: `a, b = b, a`. It's more readable, more idiomatic, and possibly even faster.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(a,b) = (20,10) if x() else (10,20)
```

Comment: Note that this will probably be more efficient if you use tuple instead of list since tuple are immutable they can be interned by the interpreter.

Answer (score 5):

Swapping values with `a, b = b, a` is considered [idiomatic in Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#swap-values).

```
a, b = 10, 20
if x(): a, b = b, a
```

One nice thing is about this is you do not repeat the `10` and `20`, so it is a little [DRY-er](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: You're repeating the *assignment*, though, so it's a bit of a wash.